# Authenticating to SQL Reportserver 2008 with a WebRequest

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, authentication, reporting-services

I am trying to download a PDF report from a SQL 2008 Report Server to my MVC controller but it is failing authentication.  When I paste the url in my browser I can navigate to the page successfully, but when I try to do it in code I get a 401 Unauthorized error.  The code is as follows

```
        var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password)

        var baseURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer"] + "/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx";

        WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(baseURL);
        myWebRequest.Credentials = networkCredential;

        WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
        myWebResponse.Close();
```

Comment: Why don't you use the SSRS webservice to achieve that?

Comment: Mostly because I didn't know it existed.  Do you have a link to an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate reports from an application, I would recommend to use the [ReportServer Web Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787%28v=sql.120%29.aspx).

You will be interested in the [Render method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc282808%28v=sql.120%29.aspx).

A code sample is provided in the documentation, to add your custom authentication information, just change the line:

```
rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

To

```
rs.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
```